# how to merge array indexes having same value in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, merge

I have a array that have values like this on every index i have a nested array having `[cats]` and `[products]`

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 6,
            [products] => 3
        ),

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 6,
            [products] => 4
        ),
   [2] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 7,
            [products] => 9
        )
)
```

i want to change this array like all `[cats]` indexes that have same value merge into single index and `[products]`index of these indexes merge into nested array

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 6
            [products] => array(
                                [0]=>3,
                                [1]=>4 )
        ),

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 7,
            [products] => 9
        )
  )
```

I have tried but my code is not working my code is this

```
$products = array(
    array(
        'cat' => 6,
        'products' => 3
    ),
    array(
        'cat' => 6,
        'products' => 4
    ),
    array(
        'cat' => 7,
        'products' => 9
    )
);
$newProducts = array();
foreach ($products as $item) {
    if (!empty($newProducts[$item['cat']])) {
        $currentValue = $newProducts[$item['cat']]['products'];
        $newProducts[$item['cat']]['products'] = $item['products'];
    } else {
        $newProducts[$item['cat']] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your attempts what you have tried so far.

Comment: Actually i am totally confused i don't know how to do this..

Comment: You might have gone through some searching tutorials or code you might have tried something and then you might have posted question on SO. or you didn't tried so far and posted directly on SO

Comment: Start with writting a `foreach`

Comment: Iterate over the array and produce a new array containing your sub-lists. I would recommend using always a sub-array under `[products]`, even if it contains only one entry. That makes it easier to create as well as to use it later on (you do not have to handle different cases for one and for multiple products).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other says you should to start with `foreach`

```
<?php

$products = array(
    array(
        'cat' => 6,
        'products' => 3
    ),
    array(
        'cat' => 6,
        'products' => 4
    ),
    array(
        'cat' => 7,
        'products' => 9
    )
);
$newProducts = array();
foreach ($products as $item) {
    if (!empty($newProducts[$item['cat']])) {
        $currentValue = (array) $newProducts[$item['cat']]['products'];
        $newProducts[$item['cat']]['products'] = array_merge($currentValue, (array) $item['products']);
    } else {
        $newProducts[$item['cat']] = $item;
    }
}
var_dump(array_values($newProducts));
```

Output looks like:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cat"]=>
    int(6)
    ["products"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(3)
      [1]=>
      int(4)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cat"]=>
    int(7)
    ["products"]=>
    int(9)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array(
        'cat'=>6,
        'product'=>3,
    ),
    array(
        'cat'=>6,
        'product'=>4,
    ),
    array(
        'cat'=>5,
        'product'=>9,
    ),
);
$catIndex = array();

foreach($array as $subarray)
{
    if(!isset($catIndex[$subarray['cat']]))
        $catIndex[$subarray['cat']] = array('cat'=>$subarray['cat'], 'products'=>array());

    $catIndex[$subarray['cat']]['products'][] = $subarray['product'];

}

var_dump(array_values($catIndex));
```

Working example: [CLICK!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/92046bda639c2171546f7f5e96a1ea70915f6324)

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This script might help.

Ignore $arr1,$arr2,$arr3. I just created them to make an array like yours.

```
$arr1 = array(
    'cat' => 6,
    'products' => 3,
);
$arr2 = array(
    'cat' => 6,
    'products' => 4,
);
$arr3 = array(
    'cat' => 7,
    'products' => 9,
);
$arr4 = array($arr1, $arr2, $arr3);

print_r($arr4);

$n = count($arr4);

for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++){
    if($arr4[$i]['cat'] == $arr4[$i+1]['cat']){
        $arr5[$i]['cat'] = $arr4[$i]['cat'];
        $arr5[$i]['products'] = array($arr4[$i]['products'],$arr4[$i+1]['products']);
    }
    else {
        $arr5[] = $arr4[$i+1];
    }
}
array_pop($arr5); // just to delete the last null index of the array,
                   //created by the loop.
print_r($arr5)
```

Output-

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 6
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 4
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat] => 7
            [products] => 9
        )

)
```